# share transactions with new participants

Tags: corda

Does Corda have the best practice how to share data for the new node into the network? For example node A has transactions and we have NEW one node B. Node A have to share transactions for the last 3 months with node B.

Could you share some examples how to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily write a flow pair for this.

The first party invokes the following flow to send all their stored transactions to a counterparty:

```
@InitiatingFlow
@StartableByRPC
class Sender(val counterparty: Party) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call() {
        val (existingTransactions, _) = serviceHub.validatedTransactions.track()
        val counterpartySession = initiateFlow(counterparty)
        counterpartySession.send(existingTransactions)
    }
}
```

The counterparty responds by invoking the following flow to receive and record all the transactions:

```
@InitiatedBy(Sender::class)
class Receiver(val counterpartySession: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call() {
        val existingTransactions = counterpartySession.receive<List<SignedTransaction>>().unwrap { it }
        serviceHub.recordTransactions(existingTransactions)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello! thank you very much for your example. Does Corda have any instrument for filtering transaction for example by timestamp? In case if I am going to synchronize states for some specific period of time?

Comment: Not currently, no.

Comment: In that case, does the counterparty become one of the participants? Will it be able to update the transaction, ie: use the received transaction's state as input and create another transaction?